# Recovery Console Commands in CMD

Tags: windows, windows-xp, cmd.exe, console

Is it possible to use the unique commands that are in recovery console but in a command prompt session?

For example LOGON, ENABLE, DISABLE, LISTSVC, MAP, SYSTEMROOT, FIXBOOT, FIXMBR, etc

I'm using windows XP.

Comment: Check %PATH% in the recovery prompt. Most probably your will find special executables for each command

Comment: @Maximus I dont quite know what to type, can you explain further? SET %PATH% does not work in recovery console

Comment: `set PATH` shows the content of `PATH` variable. Then you need to check listed folders to find tools.